# Помогите разобраться в коде!

Tags: php, html

```php
if ( $ref->num_rows == 1 and $promo->num_rows == 1 ){

$msgType = "error";
$msg = "Ошибка";

}
if ( $ref->num_rows < 1 and $promo->num_rows < 1 ){

$msgType = "error";
$msg = "Промокод не существует.";

}
if ( $ref->num_rows == 1 and $promo->num_rows != 1 and !empty($referer) ){

$msgType = "error";
$msg = "Вы уже активировали реф.код";

}
if ( $ref->num_rows == 1 and $promo->num_rows != 1 and $code == $myref ){

$msgType = "error";
$msg = "Вы не можете активировать свой реф.код";

}
else if( $ref->num_rows == 1 and $promo->num_rows != 1 ){

mysqli_query($bsd, "UPDATE `users` SET `referer` = '$code' WHERE id='$uid'");
mysqli_query($bsd, "UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` + $refsum WHERE id='$uid'");
mysqli_query($bsd, "UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` + $refsum WHERE ref_code='$code'");

}
```

Почему-то срабатывает только на последний if, я уже и через return пробовал, и объединять пытался, ничего не выходит.

Comment: Что такое `$ref`, что такое `$promo`? Какое конкретно поведение ожидается?

Comment: Это я пытаюсь настроить реферальную систему, и мне нужно, чтобы проверялись условия - чтобы код был введён не более одного раза и чтобы не вводили свой же код, однако почему-то крайняя функция else if срабатывает только на последний if

Comment: Я, честно говоря, даже с вашими пояснениями не совсем понял суть работы вашего кода. Однако, что касается последнего `else if`, то он и будет срабатывать только на последний `if`, поскольку `else if` является частью конструкции `if - else if - else` и имеет отношение только к последнему встреченному `if` в данном контексте.  Если вы хотите, чтобы это все работало в совокупности, объедините все условия в одну конструкцию `if - else if - else`